# SQL - Distribute/subtract a column from multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I have a table called `wallet` which logs all wallet transactions. Let's say there are 4 ways in which users can add money to the wallet i.e. `credit_src1,credit_src2,credit_src3,credit_src4` for which I have respective columns. Also, users can debit from their accounts, so I have a column corresponding to that.
Each transaction of credit or debit is logged in the table with corresponding transaction id. A user can perform only one operation for a transaction id.

I want to retrieve the corresponding amount left in each credit source when a user debits from wallet. Assume that amount is deducted equally from each source. If amount reaches 0 in one column, it is deducted equally from remaining columns until those reach 0.

This is the source table:

```
ID    src1    src2    src3   src4    debit
==========================================
1     10      0       0      0       0
2     10      0       0      0       0
3     0       50      0      0       0
4     0       0       40     0       0
5     0       0       0      0       30
6     0       0       0      0       70
```

Destination table should be a cumulative sum of all sources minus equal debit from each source:

```
ID    src1    src2    src3   src4    debit
==========================================
1     10      0       0      0       0
2     20      0       0      0       0
3     20      50      0      0       0
4     20      50      40     0       0
5     10      40      30     0       30
6     0       20      10     0       70
```

I can get sum of money from various sources using this query

```
SELECT
SUM(src1) OVER (ORDER BY ID),
SUM(src2) OVER (ORDER BY ID),
SUM(src3) OVER (ORDER BY ID),
SUM(src1) OVER (ORDER BY ID)
FROM wallet
```

I can't figure out how to equally distribute debit amount among all sources. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/893c6/4

Comment: For this kind of manipulation you should use stored procedures (CREATE FUNCTION), or use a programming language with which you connect to the database.

Comment: I think the only way to accomplish this is using recursive CTEs, which BigQuery does not support.

Comment: How would you do it using recursive CTEs or procedures??

Comment: What is the desired behavior when the amount of the debit exceeds the available sum of all the sources?

Comment: @AlanHadsell You can assume such a case won't occur in DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery and its BQL is quite powerful to overcome limitations mentioned in some comments to your question! At least in some cases like this one. So ...

Below does exactly what you are looking for. 
Entirely in BigQuery with use of [JS UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions)

```
SELECT id, src1, src2, src3, src4, debit FROM JS(
// input table
(
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tx) AS txs 
  FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(STRING(id), '|' , STRING(src1), '|' , 
                  STRING(src2), '|' , STRING(src3), '|' , 
                  STRING(src4), '|' , STRING(debit)
           ) AS tx
    FROM wallet
    ORDER BY id
  )
) ,
// input columns
txs,
// output schema
"[
{name: 'id', type: 'integer'},
{name: 'src1', type: 'integer'},
{name: 'src2', type: 'integer'},
{name: 'src3', type: 'integer'},
{name: 'src4', type: 'integer'},
{name: 'debit', type: 'integer'}
]",
// function
"function(r, emit){
  var tx_list = r.txs.split(',');
  var src1_total = 0;
  var src2_total = 0;
  var src3_total = 0;
  var src4_total = 0;
  var id  = 0;
  var debit = 0;
  var cut = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < tx_list.length; i ++){
    var src = tx_list[i].split('|');

    id = parseInt(src[0]);
    src1_total += parseInt(src[1]);
    src2_total += parseInt(src[2]);
    src3_total += parseInt(src[3]);
    src4_total += parseInt(src[4]);
    debit = parseInt(src[5]);
    cut = debit;

    while (cut > 0) {
      if (src1_total > 0 && cut > 0) {src1_total--; cut--;}
      if (src2_total > 0 && cut > 0) {src2_total--; cut--;}
      if (src3_total > 0 && cut > 0) {src3_total--; cut--;}
      if (src4_total > 0 && cut > 0) {src4_total--; cut--;}
    }

    emit({
      id: id, src1: src1_total, src2: src2_total,
      src3: src3_total, src4: src4_total, debit: debit
    });
  }

}"
)
```

Output:

```
id  src1    src2    src3    src4    debit    
1     10       0      0        0       0     
2     20       0      0        0       0     
3     20      50      0        0       0     
4     20      50     40        0       0     
5     10      40     30        0      30     
6      0      10      0        0      70
```

Please note:  Above solution is not scalable enough. Depends on size (row counts) of your table (wallet) you will see it sooner or later. And keep your eyes on biiling tier as it can get high with rows growing.

My recommendation: in case if you willhit limitations mentioned above - you should code logic similar to what you see in this example's udf on client of your choice